# Can we use same app-ads.txt file for multiple ad networks

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am new in android development, i have one account on admob and one on unity. For admob i have hosting where I have added app-ads.txt file.
Now my question is, Can I use the same app-ads.txt file for unity by adding unity code below the admob code

Comment: Yes, add all the identifiers in the same file.

Comment: Hay @PrathamJindal please upvote DarShan's answer and close the question so that everybody here in the wide world of StackOverflow doesn't have to click on this question and so that DarShan can get his credit for answering your question, thanks.

Comment: The mentionned answer does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, check out this example from Candy Crush makers kings

[www.king.com/app-ads.txt](https://www.king.com/app-ads.txt)

```
google.com, pub-7948746413677028, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
facebook.com, 493124377481268, RESELLER, c3e20eee3f780d68
...
unity.com, 1267328, DIRECT, 96cabb5fbdde37a7
```

Comment: @PrathamJindal  was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?